# how to handle dependency cycle dagger 2

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I have two classes `PdfTicketStorage` and `OfflineHelper` they both depend on each other.

OfflineHelper class requires PdfTicketStorage to send data to firebase

```
class OfflineHelper @Inject constructor(
    private val app: App,
    private val settings: Settings,
    private val pdfTicketStorage: PdfTicketStorage,
) {
       private fun postPrintedTicket(offlineData: OfflineData) {
      //SENDS DATA TO FIREBASE
        val offlinePrintedTicketInfo = gson.fromJson(offlineData.requestInfoJson, OfflinePrintedTicketInfo::class.java)
        pdfTicketStorage.store(offlinePrintedTicketInfo.pdfTicketFilePath, offlinePrintedTicketInfo.pdfTicketContent)
    }

    fun saveOfflineDataWithPdf() {
      //save data to database
    }
}
```

PdfTicketStorage requires offlineHelper to save data in the database

```
public class PdfTicketStorage {

    private final String cloudStorageBucket;
    private final OfflineHelper offlineHelper;

    public PdfTicketStorage(String cloudStorageBucket, OfflineHelper offlineHelper) {
        this.cloudStorageBucket = cloudStorageBucket;
        this.offlineHelper = offlineHelper;
    }

     public Single<String>  storeTest(final String filePath, final byte[] fileContents, final String fuelOrderId) {
            offlineHelper.saveOfflineDataWithPdf();
            return Single.just("");
      
    }
}
```

As both are interdependent how can resolve the dependency cycle

error i get

```
[Dagger/DependencyCycle] Found a dependency cycle:
public interface AppComponent {
       ^
      com.xx.xxx.clean.offline.OfflineHelper is injected at
          com.xx.xxx.injection.modules.ServiceModule.providePdfTicketStorage(…, offlineHelper)
      com.xx.xxx.printing.storage.PdfTicketStorage is injected at
          com.xx.xxx.clean.offline.OfflineHelper(…, pdfTicketStorage, …)
      com.xx.xxx.clean.offline.OfflineHelper is injected at
          com.xx.xxx.activities.MainActivity.offlineHelper
      com.xx.xxx.activities.MainActivity is injected at
          com.xxx.xx.injection.components.ActivityComponent.inject(com.xx.xxx.activities.MainActivity) [com.xx.xxx.injection.components.AppComponent → com.xx.xxx.injection.components.ActivityComponent]
```

ServiceModule

```
  @Provides @PerApp
    public PdfTicketStorage providePdfTicketStorage(App app, OfflineHelper offlineHelper) {
        return new PdfTicketStorage(app.getString(R.string.cloud_storage_bucket), offlineHelper);
    }
```

Could you suggest any alternatives to fix this please

thanks
R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Lazy](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/#lazy-injections)

```
public class PdfTicketStorage {

    private final String cloudStorageBucket;
    private final Lazy<OfflineHelper> offlineHelper;

    public PdfTicketStorage(String cloudStorageBucket, Lazy<OfflineHelper> offlineHelper) {
        this.cloudStorageBucket = cloudStorageBucket;
        this.offlineHelper = offlineHelper;
    }

     public Single<String>  storeTest(final String filePath, final byte[] fileContents, final String fuelOrderId) {
            offlineHelper.get().saveOfflineDataWithPdf();
            return Single.just("");
      
    }
}
```

The inconvenient is Lazy Injection directly impact parameter of your constructeur.
But if it's fine for you you can use it

Comment: I tried that but have the same error as before

Comment: This is exactly the same stack ? Not another Circular dependency ?

Comment: Can you provide us App constructor ?

Comment: app does not have any constructor. but is this what ur looking for in App.
    public void createComponent() {
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .build();
        appComponent.inject(this);
    }

    public AppComponent component() {
        return appComponent;
    }

Comment: And if you add PerApp Scope on OfflineHelpeer ?

Comment: I had to add Lazy in ServiceModule as well and the build is successful, will run it and see if it all works well.

Comment: Yes sorry thé provided Method should have same signature has construction (in your case)

Comment: thank you very much for your assistance on this